# How to create a Symfony guard without user provider

Tags: php, symfony

I have a use case where I don't have users in my application (at least this part of it).
Instead I just have a single auth token stored in the `.env`.

I tried to create a custom guard, but I keep getting errors like:

```
Not configuring explicitly the provider for the "guard" listener on "api_v1" firewall is ambiguous as there is more than one registered provider.
```

Even setting it explicityly to null gives the same error.

Here is how I configured it:

```
security:
  ...
  firewalls:
    ...
    api_v1:
      pattern: ^/api/v1
      stateless: true
      guard:
        provider: ~
        authenticators:
          - App\Security\ApiAuthenticator
```

How can I create a guard without UserProvider?

All I need is simple:
`X-AUTH === "foo"` -> give access
`X-AUTH !== "foo"` -> deny access

Comment: It you need to make the distinction between authenticated and non-authenticated users, you do need a `UserProvider`. You can consider using the [`InMemory` Provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#memory-user-provider) with a "dummy" user.